Update one field in database longtext data type in my controller
i want to update label value on my database using my controller,depending on the project_id
here is how the database look like
id
project_id
content : [{"id":1,"reference":"CM01","label":"test","status":"pending","priority":"urgent"},{"id":2,"reference":"CM02","label":"test2","status":"pending","priority":"urgent"},
.....
]

i've tried this but it's not working :
 $e_service = array_replace(json_decode($table->e_service, true), [
           'label' => $request->label,
           
       ]);
       
 $table->update([
           'e_service' => json_encode($e_service)
       ]);


thank you in advance for your help. 

If I understood your question correctly, first you need to translate your json into an array, then find the desired element by label (or better by id) and update the value, then save it again in json format.
 $model = YourModel::where('project_id', $project_id)->firstOrFail();

 $content = json_decode($model->content, true);

 foreach ($content as &$item) {
    // or $item['id'] === 1
    if ($item['label'] === $request->label) {
      $item['label'] = $request->label;
      break;
    }
 }

 $table->update([
     'content' => json_encode($content)
 ]);

